# python pandas strange group by

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `DataFrame` `df`:

```
                ga:browser ga:users
    0               Chrome     1351
    1             MRCHROME      870
    2               Chrome      630
    3            YaBrowser      601
    4            YaBrowser      567
    5              Firefox      541
.............
```

its ok
If I group by is`DataFrame` im get

```
print(df[["ga:browser", 'ga:users']].groupby(["ga:browser"])['ga:users'].sum())
```

its return

```
ga:browser
Android Browser                                                      16394331
BlackBerry                                                                  2
BrowserNG                                                                   3
Chrome                      1351630526198100776663625656514239363331242221...
Edge                                                                   132332
Firefox                      541149412827211686554433332222221111111111111111
Internet Explorer                                                 20349403171
Iron                                                                        1
MRCHROME                                                                  870
```

How i can group this?

Comment: run `df.dtypes` and report back what you see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the `dtype` of `ga:users` with `df.info()`. If it's not `int64` but rather `object` (which implies `string`, and your output looks like strings being concatenated), do

```
df['ga:users'] =df[['ga:users']].astype(int)
```